# android google heat maps is not showing locations more than 1000

Tags: android, heatmap

I implemented the google heat maps in my app and heat maps is showing my locations but if my locations count crossed 1000 then heat maps is showing only 1000 points and left the remaining points.

I use below code to implement heat maps.

```
mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
.data(list)
.radius(40)
.gradient(ALT_HEATMAP_GRADIENT)
.opacity(0.7)
.build();

mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new  TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
mOverlay.clearTileCache();
```

Please let me know how i can show all locations.

Thanks